# Is the CPu temperature of my laptop normal -> possible overheating

Tags: release-loki, cpu

I'm using Elementary OS 0.4 Loki.

When I start the laptop in the morning (the laptop is cold), if i run sensors 36° Celsius. After some time, if i open a browser, the speed fan gets to 2000 rpm and the temperature of the cpu is always between 45-50-55 Celsius (2500-2800 rpm). It's normal? It can be a overheating issue?

CPU model: Intel core i5-3317u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a normal temperature if you are watching a video or a resource intensive website. Anyway, I recommend you to install tlp (`sudo apt install tlp`) because this app is going to help with your issue. TLP is basically a daemon that monitors different sensors and is able to modify hardware settings so that your system becomes more efficient (and makes the temperatures lower).

After you install it, do `sudo tlp start` to start it and `sudo tlp-stat` to see the current settings.

To lower the temperatures, the best thing you can do is apply the settings below, run the first command and check if your settings are the same.

If the output is different you can change the settings with `sudo pantheon-text-editor /etc/default/tlp`. Don't forget to start tlp again to apply the new settings.

```
sudo tlp-stat -p 

scaling_driver = intel_pstate
scaling_governor = powersave
```

Now, this other settings you have to change them in `/etc/default/grub` . After that, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Some of the following may not be available so just change the ones that are.

```
sudo tlp-stat | grep /sys/module/i915/parameters/

/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        =  1 
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  anything between 3-7 **
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       =  0
```

---

** 7 is the most agressive and may make your videos stutter.

That's all. If it's necessary i can provide more explanations as to why I've chosen this settings. But basically I've just set your cpu settings to recommended and your intel graphics settings to a powersave mode.

`

Comment: in sys/module/i915/parameters I don't have the powersave file, but I have enable_rc6 and enable_fbc. Can you explain  what does it mean enable_rc6 and enable_fbc?

Comment: this is the result of sudo tlp-stat | grep /sys/module/i915/parameters/
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  3 (enabled + deep)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       = -1 (use per-chip default)

Comment: Rc6 is a sleep state for the GPU. And fbc, frame buffer compression, basically compresses data. Disabling fbc wont make a big impact on temperatures, so it's okay to leave it on -1.

Comment: The most important part is the CPU configuration. If you want even more you can also set `no_turbo` to 1. This will disable turboboost but will also lower the temperatures.

Comment: Do you know some documentation online where i can read in detail this settings?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics  |  

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling  |  

Also, on terminal you have `man intel ` which gives you more settings you can apply in a .conf  file inside `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ `

Comment: It's safe disabling turbo boost?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52517/discussion-between-provola-and-maccer).

Comment: Yes it's safe. But in most cases disabling it won't lower the temperature much but will increase execution times of cpu intensive programs ( compresion of packages, video editing...) You have all the important info in those links. There isn't much more i can tell you...